# Image.FromFile not loading into design time view c#.net

Tags: c#, image, xaml

I am currently trying to get an image to show in design time in my Xaml with the code below:

Xaml:

```
<Canvas Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="0,0,0,0">
    <Image Canvas.ZIndex="1" Source="{Binding Coupon.OverlayImage}"  Margin="0,-21,-76,108" Stretch="Fill" x:Name="PrintImageContextMenu" />
</Canvas>
```

C# Design Time:

```
Coupon.OverlayImage = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Temp\Images\TestImage.png");
```

Original Property of OverlayImage in VB (Legacy Code):

```
private _overlayImage as Image

Public Property OverlayImage As Image
    Get
        Return _overlayImage
    End Get
    Set
        _overlayImage = value
        NotifyPropertyChanged("OverlayImage")
    End Set
End Property
```

Upon first view I cannot see anything wrong with but it does not show, even at runtime. Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everywhere you use the `Image` class, I think you use the `System.Drawing.Image` because the WPF Image control does not have a `FromFile()` method . You cannot use it as a source for the WPF Image Control. You must instead try using an IValueConverter to convert the `Image` to a BitmapSource/ImageSource.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Image [Fallback](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingbase.fallbackvalue(v=vs.110).aspx) value to set the default image.Here is a simple example.

```
    <Window.Resources>
       <BitmapImage x:Key="ImageSource" UriSource="C:\Temp\Images\TestImage.png"/>
    </Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Image
    HorizontalAlignment="Left"
    Source="{Binding SourceImage,FallbackValue={StaticResource ImageSource}}"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Yes I was aware of this but in this project in runtime, I want the image to be defined dynamically, i.e the user would choose the file from something like an 'OpenFileDialog' and then the selected Item to populate on the screen. Is there a way to do this simply? Im sort of new to this so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
var uri = new Uri(Coupon.OverlayImage);
var bitmap = new BitmapImage(uri);
ImageName.Source = bitmap;
```